# Command to copy a line from text and create a new text file

Tags: shell

Please suggest me a command that will copy a line from all the text files and create one file with all the lines in it.

I am on a Linux machine where a particular directory has around 11000 files in it and each file has 3 or 4 lines of data.

What I wanted to do is to combine all data into one file which I can refer.... let's say 11000*3 = 3000 lines. I want to copy all 3000 lines in one single file line by line.

These are the few txt files and directories and even the directories has a list of txt files

```
Jan 2007 abc.txt
Jan 2007 siele.txt
Jan 2007 regel.txt
Jan 2007 sne.txt
Jan 2007 marshwlo.txt
Jan 2007 ziplist.txt
Jan 2007 listider.txt
Jan 2007 kindle.txt
Jan 2007 list.txt
Jan 2007 Codelevel
Jan 2007 Ziplevel
```

Comment: Can you describe better what you want? Please give some sample input and output. It would also help to show your attempted solution. See [mcve].

Comment: @JohnKugelman Sorry, if my question was not descriptive. I have updated it now. Please let me know if that helps

Comment: @JohnKugelman I found one that serves my purpose. Sorry for the confusion. command i used `awk '{print > "newfile.txt"}' *.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find . -name \*.txt -type f | xargs -r cat > /tmp/output_file.txt
```

Explained:

- `find . -name \*.txt -type f` search recursive from `.` directory for any `*.txt` file
- `xargs -r cat` run command `cat foundFile1.txt foundFile2.txt ...`
- `> /tmp/output_file.txt` redirect output to file `/tmp/output_file.txt`

Answer (score 2):

This?

```
cat *.txt > newfile.txt
```

Comment: that works too. one more question. along with 11000 text files, I also have 56 subdirectories that again has few more text files. How do I loop text files under those sub-directories?

Comment: Then look to the `find` answer or make use of `globstar` globbing in bash >= 4.0 (and if you only have a depth of two).